# Does --network=host still connect to the host network when running a Gitlab CI job with the FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD flag?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to run a test using docker in docker within a Gitlab CI job. My understanding is that enabling the FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD flag will automatically create a user-defined bridge network that the job runner and all of the created dockers within that job will connect to... but looking at the Gitlab documentation I am slightly confused...

This page: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/

Gives an example of using the `docker:dind` service with `FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD: "true"`

But then when using `docker run` they still include the `--network=host` flag.

Here is the given example:

```
  stage: build
  image: docker:19.03.1
  services:
    - docker:dind                    # necessary for docker run
    - tutum/wordpress:latest
  variables:
    FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD: "true"     # activate container-to-container networking
  script: |
    docker run --rm --name curl \
      --volume  "$(pwd)":"$(pwd)"    \
      --workdir "$(pwd)"             \
      --network=host                 \
      curlimages/curl:7.74.0 curl "http://tutum-wordpress"
```

I am trying to ensure that all of my dockers within this job are on their own separate network,
so does using the `--network=host` flag in this instance connect the new docker to the host server that the actual job runner is on? Or the per-job network that was just created? In what case would you want to create a per-job network and still connect a new docker to the host network?

Would appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> does using the --network=host flag in this instance connect the new docker to the host server that the actual job runner is on? Or the per-job network that was just created?

This is probably confusing because the "host" in `--network=host` does not mean *host* as in the underlying runner host / 'baremetal' system. To understand what is happening here, we must first understand how the `docker:dind` service works.

When you use the service `docker:dind` to power `docker` commands from your build job, you are running containers '*on*' the `docker:dind` service; it is the docker daemon.

When you provide the `--host` option to `docker run` **it refers to the host network of the *daemon* I.E. the `docker:dind` container**, not the underlying system host.

When you specify `FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD` that was specifying the docker network for the build job and its service containers that encapsulates all of your job's containers.

So, in order, the relevant activities happen as follows:

1. The GitLab runner creates a new docker network for the build
2. The runner creates the `docker:dind` and `tutum/wordpress:latest` services, connected to the network created in step (1)
3. Your job container starts, also connected to the docker network in step (1)
4. Your job contacts the `docker:dind` container and asks it to start a new `curl` container, **connected to the host network of the `docker:dind` container** -- the same network created in step (1), allowing it to reach the service containers.

Without the `--network=host` flag, the created container would be on a different bridge network and be unable to reach the network created from step (1).

Comment: This is a great explanation, thank you so much!