# Why can't I connect to selenium docker-compose service from my GitLab job?

Tags: docker, selenium, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, selenium-rc

I am running selenium test in Gitlab CI, but have problem with setting remote URL correctly when using the gitlab runner instead of my computer.

The IP address of the runner is `192.168.xxx.xxx`. And when I run the pipeline, I got the IP address of selenium hub is `172.19.0.2/16`. I  tried both, and both failed. I also tried to use the name of the selenium hub container `http://selenium__hub`, but it also failed.

The docker-compose.yml is:

```
version: "3"
services:
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:4.0.0-20211013
    container_name: chrome
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    volumes:
      - ./target:/home/seluser/Downloads
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
      - SE_NODE_GRID_URL=http://localhost:4444
    ports:
      - "6900:5900"
  edge:
    image: selenium/node-edge:4.0.0-20211013
    container_name: edge
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    volumes:
      - ./target:/home/seluser/Downloads
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
      - SE_NODE_GRID_URL=http://localhost:4444
    ports:
      - "6901:5900"
  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox:4.0.0-20211013
    container_name: firefox
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    volumes:
      - ./target:/home/seluser/Downloads
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
      - SE_NODE_GRID_URL=http://localhost:4444
    ports:
      - "6902:5900"
  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:4.0.0-20211013
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
```

the gitlab runner's config file looks like this:

```
[[runners]]
  name = "selenium"
  url = "https://gitlab.myhost.at"
  token = "xxxxxxxx"
  executor = "docker"
  privileged = true
  links = ["selenium__hub:hub"]
  [runners.docker]
    image = "docker:stable"
    privileged = true
```

The remote url I have tried are:

```
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://192.168.xxx.xxx:4444/wd/hub"), cap);
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://172.19.0.2:4444/wd/hub"), cap);
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://selenium__hub:4444/wd/hub"), cap);
```

How can I get this to work with GitLab runner?

Comment: Can edit your question to include your GitLab job configuration and job script used? That way we can know how your job is connected to the docker daemon/containers. Please also describe exactly what you mean by "failed" what exactly is the error is you are seeing. -- As a possible note, [underscores are not RFC compliant in hostnames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14622263/5747944). This _shouldn't_ be an issue for browsers, but just in case, maybe try using a different name for your hub service... but I suspect the issue is networking setup for your job.

Comment: I've edited your question title and description to improve clarity in what is being asked. Please feel free to change it back if you feel I've made any errors in this.

Comment: @sytech  I am sorry to bother you. could you have a look at another topic also related to docker and gitlab CI. Thanks.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69974278/how-to-set-up-a-selenium-test-of-download-a-file-in-gitlab-ci

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is when your job launches containers using `docker-compose`, the hostnames in the docker network are not known to your job container.

Assuming you are using the `docker:dind` service in your job to use `docker-compose` and you are trying to connect to your services started with `docker-cmpose` from your job, you would need to use the hostname `docker` to reach your services through their mapped ports.

So your corrected code would be as follows:

```java
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://docker:4444/wd/hub"), cap);
```

### Why "docker"?

The reason this is needed is because your containers are running 'on' a remote docker daemon service -- the `docker:dind` container. When you invoke `docker-compose` your job container talks to the `docker:dind` container which in turn spins up a new docker network and creates the docker containers in your compose file on that network.

Your job container has no knowledge of (or route to) that network, nor does it know the hostnames of the services. The service daemon itself also is running on a separate network from your runner -- because it is another docker container that was created by the docker executor; so your runner IP won't work either.

However, the docker executor *does* create a link to your `services:` I.E. the `docker:dind` service. So you can reach *that* container by the `docker` hostname. Additionally, your compose file indicates that the hub service should make a port mapping of `4444:4444` from the host -> continaer. The host, in this case, means the `docker:dind` service. So calling `http://docker:4444` from your job reaches the hub service.

### Why doesn't "links" work?

Finally, to cover one last detail, it looks like in your runner configuration you expected your `links` to allow you to communicate with the hub container by hostname:

```
  links = ["selenium__hub:hub"]
```

In the runner configuration, it's true that the `links` configuration, in general, would allow your job to communicate with containers by hostname. However, this configuration is errant for two reasons:

1. This configuration can only apply to containers *alongside* your runner container. That is other containers registered on the host daemon -- not containers created by other docker daemons, like the ones created with `docker-compose` in your job by talking to the `docker:dind` service daemon.
2. Even if you *could* reach containers created by other daemons, or your hub container was created by the host daemon, the parameters are wrong, according to the URLS you tried. This configuration basically says "expose the `selenium__hub` container as the FQDN `hub`" -- but you never tried the hostname `hub`.

There is nothing to *fix* here because (1) is not a fixable error when using docker-in-docker.

### Alternatives

Alternatively, you can utilize GitLab's `services:` capability to run the hub and/or browser containers.

```yaml
my_job:
  services:
    - docker:dind
    - name: selenium/hub:4.0.0-20211013
      alias: hub  # this is the hostname
```

You could even do this as a runner configuration and give it a special tag and jobs needing remote browsers can just add the necessary `tags:` key(s) to reduce the amount of job configuration needed.

You may also be interested to see one of [my other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69847589/5747944) on how `FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD` feature flag can affect how networking works between docker containers and jobs/services.

Comment: Hi, @sytech Thank you so much. your suggestion "http://docker:4444/wd/hub" works. And it is the first time I saw these so clearly and useful explaining about how to use docker in docker in the pipeline. Thank you so much again. :)

Comment: Hi @sytech , would you be so kind as to help me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75397786/2806819)? I've also tried the `docker:4444` (for Grid 4) but to no avail.