# Unable to connect Selenium Grid 4 in GitLab CI using Docker in Docker

Tags: docker, selenium, gitlab

Selenium Grid 4 uses `http://localhost:4444` instead of `http://localhost:4444/wd/hub` which is Selenium Grid 3. Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69915035) thread, I used `http://docker:4444` as below.

.gitlab-ci.yml:

```
variables:
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository"
  # Other vars
  SELENIUM_GRID_URL: "http://docker:4444"

cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository/
    - target/

stages:
  - build
  - test

compile:
  stage: build
  image: maven:3.8.7-eclipse-temurin-17
  script: mvn compile

docker-selenium:
  stage: test
  image: docker:23.0.0
  services:
    - docker:23.0.0-dind
  script:
    - docker compose up -d

junit:
  stage: test
  needs: ["docker-selenium"]
  image: maven:3.8.7-eclipse-temurin-17
  script: mvn test -Dparallel-enabled=true -Dthread-count=7
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:latest
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
      - SE_NODE_MAX_SESSIONS=8
      - SE_NODE_OVERRIDE_MAX_SESSIONS=true
      - SE_VNC_NO_PASSWORD=1
      - SE_VNC_VIEW_ONLY=1

  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox:latest
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
      - SE_NODE_MAX_SESSIONS=8
      - SE_NODE_OVERRIDE_MAX_SESSIONS=true
      - SE_VNC_NO_PASSWORD=1
      - SE_VNC_VIEW_ONLY=1

  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:latest
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
```

The `RemoteWebDriver` is instantiated like this:

```
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(gridUrl, options)
```

Exception when I use `docker` as hostname:

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: docker
```

Exception when I use `localhost` as hostname:

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:4444
```

Comment: Where is your GitLab running?

Comment: If  they are running within the same virtua; network you should use `selenium-hub` as the host name to your grid.

Comment: @AlexeyR. I am using whatever the default runner is for pipelines (new to GitLab, didn't alter anything in the project settings apart from env vars). Unfortunately, using `http://selenium-hub:4444` also threw the `UnknownHostException`. Any ideas?

Comment: I mean if it runs on host machine where docker is running or it runs also within a container or it runs on different physical machine

Comment: gitlab is just a service. It has to be hosted somewhere. Alright. let me focus my question. Do you know where your tests run. On which machine. So we do understand where we would like to connect. It is your selenium hub container. But now we should also understand **where we are connecting from**.

Comment: I'm using this "shared runner" that is provided by default in the GitLab pipelines. I did not config any machine (physical or virtual), just these 2 YAML files. The shared runner runs the tests on some default agent I don't know.

Comment: Where do you deploy your selenium container? Also sometwhere in the cloud or on your local machine?

Comment: All in the cloud. Everything via the shared runner provided in GitLab pipelines by default.

Comment: @k_rollo I am facing the same issue. Were you able to resolve this?